# How does AAD API Access delegate permission work?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azureportal

I'm having a little trouble following how API Access delegate permissions work with azure active directory.  I feel like i'm probably misunderstanding a key aspect of how AAD works.

Here is my set up

1. I have a Web Application let’s call it WebApp.  I have created
   an AAD for the Web Application and registered with a AAD App ID. Let’s
   call it App ID A
2. I have a Web Api let’s call it ApiService.  I have also created an AAD for it and registered with a AAD App ID.  Let’s all it App ID B.
3. In AAD App ID A, I have updated the clicked on the API Access ->
   Required Permissions -> Add (App ID B ; Web API) permissions
4. I’ve updated the manaifest in the AAD App ID B, to give consent to
   knownClientApplications to include the client ID of the Web App
5. I’ve also enable oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to be true for both App’s
   manifest.

What I’m trying to do is, A user signs into the web application sign.  When it signs in, the user is able to acquire a token for the specific Web App App ID A.  The user should be able to use that token and have access the Api Service with App ID B.  I thought by configuring the whole API Access -> Required Permissions within the Web Application it would give me delegate permission with the logged in user to communicate with the Api Service WebApi.

When I examine the JWT token, I notice that there is a claim for Microsoft Graph, but not for the ApiService.  Shouldn’t I be seeing a claim?

When I try to use the token, it reacts with a 404 authentication error.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

### UPDATE

In response to @joonasw

I actually looked at the example you wrote when i started.

https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication

In the example, the web application is initialized with:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
        {
        Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(opts);
            opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = ctx =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
        });
```

In the HomeController, there is code to retrieve the token for the graph api

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    string authority = _authOptions.Authority;

    string userId = User.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
    var cache = new AdalDistributedTokenCache(_cache, _dataProtectionProvider, userId);

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, cache);

    //App's credentials may be needed if access tokens need to be refreshed with a refresh token
    string clientId = _authOptions.ClientId;
    string clientSecret = _authOptions.ClientSecret;
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        credential,
        new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

From my understanding, when the user initially login to the web application it will trigger the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived() method where it will be using the clientId/clientSecret/resource of the web applicaiton.  The token is stored in the distributed token cache under the key resource/client id.

In the example, GetAccessTokenAsync() is used to grab the token to access the graph API.

In my case, I was hoping to update that method to retrieve the token for the WebApi which has a different clientId/clientSecret/resoruce.  In my case, it will AcquireTokenSilentAsync will throw an AdalTokenAcquisitionExceptionFilter because the token needed is not stored in the cache and in the AdalTokenAcquisitionExceptionFilter  it will call try to reauthenticate

```
context.Result = new ChallengeResult();
```

which will redirect to the authentication page and then hits the AddOpenIdConnect() method.  However, the openIdConnect is configured with the web app clientID/ClientSecret/Resource and will not store the new token properly.  It will try to call GetAccessTokenAsync() again and the whole process will go in an infinite loop.

In the example, if you were to comment out the "Anthentication:resource" in app.settings, you will experience the same issue with the infinite loop.  What happens is that you initially authenticate correctly with no resource specified.  Then when you click on you try to get the token for microsoft graph which is a new resource, it can't find it in the cache and then tries to reauthenticate over and over again.

I also notice that the acquireAsyncAuthentication only returns a AuthenticationResult with a bearer tokentype.  How would you get the refresh token in this case?

Any advice?
Thanks,
Derek

### UPDATE (Solution)

Thanks to @jaanus.  All you have to do is update the resource to the clientid of the web api and pass that into AcquireTokenSilentAsync.  The web api id uri that you can get from the azure portal did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it seems there are multiple questions here. I'll try to make some sense of this stuff to you.

Adding the "Web App"'s client id to the "ApiService" knownClientApplications is a good idea.
It allows for consent to be done for both apps at the same time. This really only matters for multi-tenant scenarios though.

Now, your Web App will be acquiring access tokens at some point.
When it does, it must specify a `resource` parameter.
This parameter says to AAD which API you wish to call.
In the case of the "ApiService", you should use either its client id or Application ID URI (this is more common).

Depending on the type of your Web App, the access token is acquired a bit differently.
For "traditional" back-end apps, the Authorization Code Grant flow is usually used.
In this flow your back-end gets an authorization code after the user logs in, and your Web App can then exchange that code for the access token.

In the case of a front-end JavaScript app, you would use the Implicit Grant flow, which you have allowed (no need to enable it in the API by the way).
This one allows you to get access tokens directly from the authorization endpoint (/oauth2/authorize) without talking to the token endpoint as you usually have to.
You can actually get the access token right away after login in the fragment of the URL if you wish.
ADAL.JS makes this quite a lot easier for you if you are going in this route.

The reason you get the authentication error is because the access token is probably meant for Microsoft Graph API. You need to request an access token for your API.
An access token is always only valid for one API.

Comment: Thank's for the response.  I've updated my post with more details.  The problem is when i specify the resource, I get an infinite loop which might be a result of my setup.  I based my setup off the example you put out which was really helpful, but I think i'm missing an aspect on how openId should be configured and how it's stored in the distributed cache when dealing with two different app ids.

Comment: "This one allows you to get access tokens directly from the authorization endpoint (/oauth2/authorize) without talking to the token endpoint as you usually have to."  Don't you have to mark the Web API  AAD endpoint as native vs. web api to achieve this?

Comment: So what you must do in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived is exchange the code for tokens. You can use it twice for two different resources. ADAL will then cache the tokens using its token cache. Which in my example is backed by a distributed cache. Then later you can use AcquireTokenSilent to get a token from the cache. Since AAD gives a refresh token too when you exchange the code, ADAL will automatically refresh the token if needed.

Comment: Implicit flow is meant for single page apps and can be enabled on either type via the manifest. Though basically single page apps should be marked native since they run on user device.

Comment: Oh, and remember, in the Web App side when exchanging tokens, you must use the Web App's client id and secret, and use the API's client id/app id URI as the resource.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you mean "exchange the code for tokens". Can you give me an excample?  In the GetAccessTokenAsync I've replaced the resource with the API's app id url that I grabbed from the azure portal.   However, the token I get does not work on calling the web api and AuthroizationCodeRecieved does not get called the second time.  I don't really know what to update on the OnAuthroizationCodeReceived.  It seem that the cache stores the distributed cache by user id.   So in both cases, the key would be the user id.  Does the key need to be changed to map to the resource?

Comment: No, in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, when acquiring a token with `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync`, you need to specify the resource correctly as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165468/discussion-between-darewreck-and-juunas).